# How to use hex numbers as a parameters

Tags: python, hex

My job for this program is to write a function titled drawPolygonFilled() that has three parameters (the number of sides for the
polygon, the color of the edge, and the color of the fill). Using the value received as parameter, draws a regular polygon using “for”, colors the edges and fills the shape according to the parameter values. The parameters for the colors must be in hex notation.

I've already written code to draw polygons. Now I am working on trying to fill the polygons with a certain color, but my problem is how would I use the hex notation in parameters of the function?

**code:**

```
from turtle import *

#use #dccdc
def  drawPolygonFilled(n, filledColor):
    filledColor = hex(filledColor)
    Turtle()
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(n):
        left(360/n)
        forward(100)
    color(filledColor)
    end_fill()
    done()
drawPolygonFilled(4,dccdc) #error
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the color as a string like this:

```
drawPolygonFilled(4, "#dccdc")
```

Note you do not need to convert this to hex so remove that from your code.

Comment: that doesn't work either, that only allows me to draw the shape. I does not allow me to color the shape using the hex as a parameters of coloring. How would I get the compiler to understand that what I type in the second parameter is hexa and not a string. since usually the hex() function returns the hex of the parameters. I need that program to read to parameter that is given as hex and also how do I make the color() read hex?

Comment: No problem could you please accept my answer so people know that this works.